# Match literal string '\$'

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to match literal string '\$'. I'm escaping both '\' and '$' by backslash. Why isn't working when I escape the backslash in the pattern? But if I use a dot then it works.

```
import re

print re.match('\$','\$')
print re.match('\\\$','\$')
print re.match('.\$','\$')
```

Output:

```
None
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fb89cef7b90>
```

Can someone explain what's happening internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need more backslashes. You need to escape them to indicate that they're literals in the string and get them into the expression, and then further escape them to indicate that they're literals instead of regex special characters. This is why raw strings are often used for regular expressions: the backslashes don't explode.

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.match('\$','\$')
None
>>> print re.match('\\\$','\$')
None
>>> print re.match('.\$','\$')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01E1F800>
>>> print re.match('\\\\\$','\$')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01E1F800>
>>> print re.match(r'\\\$','\$')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01E1F800>
```

Comment: Careful there, you almost summoned Ba'al the Soul-Eater

Comment: @wim - "Almost"? I should backslash harder, then.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the [re.escape()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape) function for this:

> **escape(string)**
>
> Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is useful
>   if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular
>   expression metacharacters in it.

For example:

```
import re
val = re.escape('\$') # val = '\\\$'
print re.match(val,'\$')
```

It outputs:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='\\$'>
```

This is equivalent to what `@TigerhawkT3` mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40924127/5352399).

Comment: how to unescape?

Answer (score 1):

```
r'string'
```

is the **raw** string

try annotating your regex string

here are the same re's with and without raw annotation

```
print( re.match(r'\\\$', '\$'))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='\\$'>


print( re.match('\\\$', '\$'))
None
```

this is python3  on account of because

Comment: Can you explain what's happening internally?

Comment: not as well as TFM  https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html?highlight=raw%20string

Comment: dot matches anything but  new line. your target string  '\$' is not a newline so it matches.

Answer (score 1):

In a (non-raw) string literal, backslash is special. It means the Python interpreter should handle following character specially. For example `"\n"` is a string of length 1 containing the newline character. `"\$"` is a string of a single character, the dollar sign. `"\\$"` is a string of two characters: a backslash and a dollar sign.

In regular expressions, the backslash also means the following character is to be handled specially, but in general the special meaning is different. In a regular expression, `$` matches the end of a line, and `\$` matches a dollar sign, `\\` matches a single backslash, and `\\$` matches a backslash at the end of a line.

So, when you do `re.match('\$',s)` the Python interpreter reads `'\$'` to construct a string object `$` (i.e., length 1) then passes that string object to `re.match`. With `re.match('\\$',s)` Python makes a string object `\$` (length 2) and passes that string object to `re.match`.

To see what's actually being passed to `re.match`, just print it.  For example:

```
pat = '\\$'
print "pat :" + pat + ":"
m = re.match(pat, s)
```

People usually use raw string literals to avoid the double-meaning of backslashes.

```
pat = r'\$' # same 2-character string as above
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above answers. I am adding this answer because we don't have a short summary in the above answers.

The backslash `\` needs to be escaped both in python string and regex engine.

Python string will translate 2 `\\` to 1 `\`. And regex engine will require 2 `\\` to match 1 `\`

So to provide the regex engine with 2 `\\` in order to match 1 `\` we will have to use 4 `\\\\` in python string.

`\\\\` --> Python(string translation) ---> `\\` ---> Regex Engine(translation) ---> `\`

Answer (score -1):

You have to use . as . matches any characters except newline.